# Maven ignoring variables in child pom

Tags: java, build, maven-3

i been stuck with this for a while.
I am trying to automate the build and deploy (in nexus3) of several java modules and remove the need for manually set the module version in the projects pom.

My issue is that maven is ignoring the variables inside the pom files.

Parent pom:

```
<properties>
  <revision>local</revision>
</properties>

<name>lib-cloud</name>
<groupId>com.company.lib</groupId>
<artifactId>lib-cloud</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>lib-cloud-main</module>
</modules>
```

and the child pom:

```
<properties>
    <unrelatedVAR>2017.3.3</unrelatedVAR>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>lib-cloud-main</artifactId>
<name>lib-cloud-main</name>
```

and then i build this with:

```
mvn -Drevision=3.1 clean package deploy
```

This build the code just fine, create a lib-cloud-main/target/lib-cloud-main-3.1.jar

In side the jar, i can already see that 
lib-cloud-main-3.1.jar/maven/com.company.lib/lib-cloud-main/pom.xml have

```
<version>${revision}</version>
```

As version, instead 3.1 as i would expected, but still this artifact manages to be saved in nexus.

If i try to use it, however, maven trow the error when trying to get the pom:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core-backend-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.core:core-backend-api:jar:local: Failed to collect dependencies at com.company.lib:lib-cloud-main:jar:3.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.company.lib:lib-cloud-main:jar:3.1: Could not transfer artifact com.company.lib:lib-cloud:pom:${revision} from/to company-maven-public (http://mvn.company.local/repository/maven-public/): Failed to transfer file: http://mvn.company.local/repository/maven-public/com/company/lib/lib-cloud/$%7Brevision%7D/lib-cloud-$%7Brevision%7D.pom. Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Invalid repository path.
```

I even tried to use

```
mvn release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=3.1
```

As a way to overwrite the poms with a static value before the build but this methos STILL fail to touch the  tag in any project children pom.

What i am doing wrong?

> Apache Maven 3.5.4 (Red Hat 3.5.4-4) Maven home: /usr/share/maven Java
>   version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.fc29.x86_64/jre
>   Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux",
>   version: "5.0.17-200.fc29.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Answer (score 0):

You should use [release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html) to do this.

`mvn release:update-versions -DautoVersionSubmodules=true`